# Query Oracle Database by Python

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, automation, robotframework

I want query Database by using python

This is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import os

def GetDatabase(queryCommand, row):
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('Bell/Bell#@nn.nnn.nnn.nn:1521/Bell')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(queryCommand)
    res=cur.fetchone()
    i = 0
    while (i < row):
        if cur.rowcount == row:
            print res
        res=cur.fetchone()
        i = i + 1
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

tup1=GetDatabase("select Name from  ContactPoint  where EmployeeID='1234'",2)
```

This is output

```
('KANOK BKK',)
```

I just want value (I don't want parentheses and a comma)

I try print tup1[0] but it is not working.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to include an actual IP address.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `yield` instead of `print`, or put `res` into a `list` and return it, as `print` just write it to `sys.stdout`.

```
for row in tup1:  
    print(row[0])
```

Comment: I try

for row in tup1:  
print(row[0])

but it is not working.

Error

for row in tup1
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Have you change `print res` to `yield res`? `NoneType` ==>`GetDatabase`  return `None` , that means you haven't do  correctly as my suggections. Please read carefully!